# How do I "install" SQLite on my student domain?

Tags: sqlite, web-applications, installation

I've played around with SQLite on my Windows desktop before, but I've never used it in a web context and their web documentation is maddenigly unspecific about things like this. Essentially, I have free student webspace from my school (a /public/html/ directory) and I'd like to use it for a small data-driven web project. SQLite is my only (free) option and I'm wondering how to... "install" it in this context? More specifically, is it safe just to throw the files in the html directory and call it a day?

If it helps, I'm pretty sure it's Linux environment (they run Apache).

Comment: I have virtually no access to any other part of the server except for my public HTML folder. It's *very* locked down unless you run a university club. No SQL, no Ruby or PHP or any other language. The only thing you can do is drop files in. This is why I'm hoping the SQLite approach will work. But I would literally have to copy-paste the files in. I can't use server commands or sudo or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

See if it's already installed. Try the following in a bash session:

```
touch test.db
sqlite3 test.db
```

If not, you'll have to download and install sqlite3.

Useful tip: if you've been trying to run the 'sqlite' binary, it probably doesn't exist. It's called 'sqlite3'.

Comment: Good suggestion, but doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Then you have to download and install sqlite3. If you're on a Linux system, try 'sudo apt-get install sqlite3', or use whatever package manager is installed on your system. Also, check /usr/local/bin for sqlite3. If it's there and you can't call it, add it to your PATH variable in ~/.bash_profile.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is an *embedded* database; it is typically not installed, but compiled into whatever program is used to access the database.

All the typical server-side extension languages ([PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php), [Ruby](http://rubygems.org/gems/sqlite3-ruby), [Python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html), [Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~msergeant/DBD-SQLite-0.31/lib/DBD/SQLite.pm) etc.) have support modules for SQLite.

You have to check which one of those are installed on the server, and whether SQLite support has been enabled for them.

Comment: My school's server doesn't really work that way. Unless you're a school organization, you don't get access to backend server languages. You get a public HTML directory and that's it. Now, if I could make SQLite work in that, I'd be golden. That's what I'm looking for.